# javascript read object out an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

how can i read the name of the player in de list?

```
let Players = []

let Player = {
    sprite: 1,
    coords: {M: 0, X: 0, Y: 0},
    name: ""
}

function LoadPlayers(){

console.log("total players: " + Players.length)

let player1 = Player
player1.sprite = 0
player1.coords = {M: 0, X: 6, Y: 1};
player1.name = "jimpie"

Players.push([player1]);



let player2 = Player         
player2.sprite = 0
player2.coords =  {M: 0, X: 1, Y: 17};
player2.name = "kolien"

Players.push([player2]);

console.log("total players: " + Players.length)

console.log("Player 1 name: " + Players[1].name)
console.log("Player 2 name: " + Players[0].name)
}
```

I'm getting 'undefined' now and i want to read out the player details from a specific player in the list.

Comment: You're missing some `new`s in your `let _ = Player` lines, it seems.

Comment: Where are you getting undefined? Is Players defined somewhere else in the code? What about Player?

Comment: Also, you haven't instantiated a `Players` array (not in that code, at least)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not creating a `Player` correctly. Instead of using `let player1 = Player`, use `let player1 = new Player()`. Also, you need to create a `Players` array. Lastly, you'll need to make a `Player` class.

```js
class Player {
  constructor(sprite, coords, name) {
    this.sprite = sprite;
    this.coords = coords;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
var Players = []; // If you want to access this array
// from outside thefunction, keep it here. 
// Otherwise, move it in the LoadPlayers function

function LoadPlayers() {

  let player1 = new Player(0, {
    M: 0,
    X: 6,
    Y: 1
  }, "jimpie");

  Players.push(player1);



  let player2 = new Player(0, {
    M: 0,
    X: 1,
    Y: 17
  }, "kolien")

  Players.push(player2);

  console.log("total players: " + Players.length)

  console.log("Player 1 name: " + Players[0].name)
  console.log("Player 2 name: " + Players[1].name)
}

LoadPlayers();
```

Comment: You need to define a `Player` class for this to work (if that's what you mean)

Comment: sorry, forgot to put all code lines in. made an edit in my first post. it says with new Player() that player is not a constructor

Comment: If the answer was correct, please accept it (click the checkmark) to show that it solved your problem. This serves as an indicator to anyone else who finds the question which answer worked.

Comment: Can you show the code of your `Player` class in the question?

Comment: I did, there is no player class. i have: let Player = {
    sprite: 1,
    coords: {M: 0, X: 0, Y: 0},
    name: ""
} it says two times Player 1 name: kolien, Player 2 name: kolien in the console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216156/discussion-between-alexh-and-perry).

Answer (score 1):

You have different errors.

First, you must use `new Player()` instead of just `player`.

Second, you should use this:

```js
Players.push(player1);
```

instead of this:

```js
Players.push([player1]);
```

The first one pushes player1 to the array of Players, the second one pushes a new array that only contains player1 to the array Players. You must also use this to add player2.

Comment: The code would still *work* if it remained as `Players.push([player1])`. However, to access the player, one would use `Players[i][0]` instead of `Players[i]`.

Comment: Also, `Player()` needs a `new`

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that's what OP wanted.

Comment: Thank you @AlexH!

Comment: In response to 'Yes, but I don't think that's what OP wanted': It could go either way. It's best to show both methods and detail the results of each one, so the OP can choose which was best.

Comment: In this case, the first one has no advantages. A nested array is just not needed here, especially if that array only contains only one element and it's not probable that any elements will be added to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216154/discussion-between-alexh-and-leo848).

Comment: it still dont work :(  it shows by both players 'kolien'

Comment: maybe you wrote same index accidently @Perry ?

Answer (score 0):

thanks @AlexH

```
function Player(sprite, coords, name){
    this.sprite = sprite;
    this.coords = coords;
    this.name = name;
}

let Players = []

function LoadPlayers(){

console.log("total players: " + Players.length)

let player1 = new Player(1, [32, 15, 14], "jimpie")

Players.push(player1);



let player2 = new Player(1, (1, 1, 1), "kolien")

Players.push(player2);

console.log("total players: " + Players.length)

console.log("Player 1 name: " + Players[0].coords)
console.log("Player 2 name: " + Players[1].name)

var allcoords = Players[0].coords
var xcoord = allcoords[1]
var ycoord = allcoords[2]
var mapnum = allcoords[0]

console.log("map: " + mapnum + " x: " + xcoord + " y: " + ycoord);

}
```

this works fine!